# chef database cookbook failing on raw sql

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying execute a raw sql for creating a user with few grants, but I am getting a undefined method error. I am using v4.0.9 of the database chef cookbook.

```
mysql_database[create random grants] action query

       ================================================================================
       Error executing action `query` on resource 'mysql_database[create datadog grants]'
       ================================================================================

       NoMethodError
       -------------
       undefined method `close' for nil:NilClass

       Cookbook Trace:
       ---------------
       /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/database/libraries/provider_database_mysql.rb:153:in `close_query_client'

       Resource Declaration:
       ---------------------
       # In /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/xxxx/recipes/xxxxxx.rb

       156: mysql_database 'create random grants' do
       157:   connection mysql_connection_info
       158:   sql "GRANT SELECT, PROCESS, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'dummy';"
       159:   #sql 'SELECT 1'
       160:   action :query
       161: end
       162:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use the [`database` cookbook](https://github.com/chef-boneyard/database), then it was deprecated long time ago -- the development on it stopped more than 2 years ago and its repository is archived.

here is the deprecation message:

> This cookbook has been deprecated. The original intent was to abstract database implementation details away from the end user. In hindsight this was a mistake as it is difficult / impossible to make a generic interface for databases that works accross all systems. Instead we plan to move the individual providers into their respective cookbooks (mysql, postgresql, sqlite, sql_server) where they can fully utilize the feature set of the underlying DB systems.

i suggest you keep away from this cookbook.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was aware of the cookbook being deprecated. This is technical debt. Decided to finally write our own custom chef resources for doing MySQL operations.

Comment: @JeetendraPujari: if i answered your question, please mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same position and I'm using this deprecated cookbook. In order to run that resource you need to use specific cookbook revision - `depends 'database', '4.0.8'`

so if you add that to your `metadata.rb` your code from above will work.

This is the code on my side:

```rb
mysql_database 'create slave user' do
    connection mysql_connection_info
    sql "GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'slave_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '#{slave_password_data_bag_item['password']}'"
    action :query
end
```